# Angular JS - Resolve object can't retrieve in Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router, ecmascript-6, angularjs-components

I am having some trouble injecting the `resolved` object into `controller`. I am using AngularJS 1.5 Component based + ES6 syntax

heres the `routes.js` file:

I want to get the `resolved object` `garage` and inject it to my `GarageViewController` but somehow `garage` seemed to be undefined when I injected it after.

Am I missing some process or I'm just been confused for something, I don't know where I did wrong.

Please help, suggestions really appreciated.

```
const MainRoutes = ($stateProvider, $locationProvider, $urlRouterProvider) => {
"ngInject";

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!');
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
// Define the routes
$stateProvider
.state('dashboard.garage-view', {
   url: '/dashboard/garage/:id',
   template: '<garage-view></garage-view>',
   views: { 
      '': { template: '<garage-view></garage-view>' },
     'content@dashboard.garage-view': { 
          templateUrl: 'src/app/templates/garage.view.template.html' 
     },
    resolve: {
       garage: (GarageService,$stateParams) => {
        return GarageService.getGarage($stateParams.id)
      }
    }
  });
export default MainRoutes;
```

here's the `garage.service.js`:

I have used `$q` to create promise function for `getGarage(id)` to be used in `routes.js`

```
class GarageService {

  constructor($http,$location,CONFIG_CONSTANTS,$q, AuthService) {
    this.API_URL = CONFIG_CONSTANTS.API_URL;
    this.$http = $http;
    this.$location = $location;
    this.$q = $q;
    this.api_token = AuthService.api_token;
  }

  getGarage(id) {
    const deferred = this.$q.defer();
    this.$http.get(`${this.API_URL}/garage/${id}?api_token=${this.api_token}`)
      .success(response => deferred.resolve(response))
      .error(error =>  deferred.reject(error));
    return deferred.promise;
  }
}

GarageService.$inject = [
  '$http',
  '$location',
  'CONFIG_CONSTANTS',
  '$q',
  'AuthService'
];

export default GarageService;
```

here's the `GarageViewController.js`

```
class GarageViewController {
     constructor(garage) {
       console.log(garage)
     }
}


GarageViewController.$inject = ['garage'];
export default GarageViewController;
```

Comment: What is the connected between state and GarageViewController?

Comment: You don't need to return a deferred.promise as calling $http.get() already returns a promise.